# Theorem $10$ part $ii$ of the paper $I$ and $I^*$ convergence in topological spaces by P.Das and D.K. Lahiri

Tags: general-topology, ideals, proof-explanation, separation-axioms

[this paper](http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/134133/MathBohem_130-2005-2_3.pdf) pg 159-160 th $10.$ In the proof where $A=\{a_1,a_2...\}$ a countable set with $\bar A=F$ and the sequence $\{x_n\}$ is taken such that $x_n=a_i$ when $n\in M_i.$ Upto this point is fine. It then says **'We thus obtain a subsequence $\{k_n\}$, say, of the sequence $\{n\}$ of positive integers'** Which subsequence are they talking about $?$ And then the sequence $\{x_{k_n}\}$ and the proof is taken further. But what are the $k_n$'s ?

Thank you.

Comment: I think the $k_n$ is the $i$ of $M_i$ or $a_i$. It maybe should say let $x_{k_n}=a_i$ instead of $x_n = a_i$, but honestly I am not sure. If it's any consolation, there is at least another person on planet Earth who finds the line difficult to read.

Comment: @William : I had thought the same too but the reverse inclusion proof confused me because in that case $\{n; x_{k_n} ∈ U\}$  cannot contain the whole of  $M$ , it will only contain one element of $M.$